# R Combine more than two lists elements with RegEx

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have multiple lists starting with the same name.

```
(values_1, values_2,values_n)
```

Is there a way to combine them like

```
all_lists <- c(values_*)
```

Comment: `list_data <- mget(ls(pattern = 'values_'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Ronak Shah comment:

### You have to work with the global environment `.GlobalEnv`

#### The function `ls` returns all the objects already defined in the .GlobalEnv

The `pattern` parameter allows you to obtain only objects which match the pattern.

`ls()` returns a character vector with the names of the objects.

#### To access the value of objects with their names, you have to use the `get()` function

When you have multiple names, you can use `mget()`. So the final snippet is

```
list_data <- mget(ls(pattern = 'values_'))
```

---

#### If you want to do the same with dataframes

Here is a working example:

```
mtc_1 <- mtcars
mtc_2 <- mtcars
mtc_3 <- mtcars

list_data <- mget(ls(pattern = 'mtc_')) 
do.call(rbind, list_data)
```